# Hibernate LazyCollection with custom filter

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I want to get number of active entities so I have the filter:

```
@FilterDef(name = "onlyActive",
       defaultCondition = "IS_ACTIVE = '1'")
```

then I use it with lazyCollection:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "databaseInstance")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@Filter(name = "onlyActive")
public List<CloudInstance> getCloudInstances() {
    return cloudInstances;
}
```

filter is added to the session, lazy collection is initialized but when calling

```
getCloudInstances().size();
```

I get

```
select count(ID) from CLOUD_INSTANCES where databaseInstance_ID =?
```

It does not append IS_ACTIVE = '1' to the query, so the filter does not work. When I remove @LazyCollection and add eager fetch the filter works correctly. Is it possible to make this filter working with lazy collection?